# instantiating a object on the fly a static method?

Tags: php

I'm not so sure what the following object instantiation is called but it comes from a article that i'm reading.

```
class foo
{
    function out()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

echo (new foo())->out();
```

The object is instantiated automatically and calls the out method. But what i dont really understand is when i rename the out() method into a fictitious method i get an error like this:

example:

```
class foo
{
    function out()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

echo (new foo())->ou();

Fatal error: Call to undefined method foo::ou() in ...
```

Is this method somehow being called as a static method?

Comment: In your second example, the method is still named `out` in the object, but you try to call `ou`

Comment: @Lepidosteus Very true, but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @GolezTrol: which is why this was a comment, and not an answer

Comment: @Lepidosteus That's not the point. SarmenHB deliberately made this error in the code to produce the error, and has a question about the exact description in the error message, not about why the error occurs in the first place. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol: I know. But writing broken code on purpose and then trying to figure out internals from it is not a good way to learn how a language works; just wait until he gets in the land of undefined behavior...

Comment: @Lepidosteus Have you read the question? It is merely "Why does the error message say '::' when I call it using '->'. It's not about figuring out internals. He's just questioning his understanding about his own written code, which I think is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::` does not stand for `static method`, this is a missconception. The `::` is a "scope resolution operator", it denotes the identification of a method by its class predicated full name.

So this simply means: "method 'ou' as defined by class 'foo'". Not more, not less.

Answer (score 2):

No. The error just indicates that the method doesn't exist. It always shows the `::` for this error, no matter whether you call the method in a static way or not. You would get the same error if you changed the code to:

```
$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->ou();
```

Second code example as per request in comments:

```
$moo = new moo(); // Parentheses optional, I guess
$foo = new foo($moo);
$foo->out();
```

Comment: one more question, sorry to be almost irrelivent to the question above but how would something like this look written out like your answer?  (new foo(new moo))->out();

Comment: thanks, so is your example somehow related to doing something like this?: function foo(moo $myvar) { ... } or its a different story

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. That declaration is a function declaration for foo, rather than a class declaration. It uses type hinting to force you to pass an actual 'moo' to the function. If you pass something else, PHP will give an error.